# "illegal start of type" error & class breakdown

Tags: java

I am completely stumped.  I'm a beginner in java programming.  I have the following code, and cannot understand why I am getting the "illegal start of type" error on my public static void line.  Please help.

Also: How can I break this growing program into more than one class?

```
`package annual.salary;

 /*Annual Salary Calculator
 * Version 1.1
 */

 import java.util.Scanner; //Program uses Scanner
 import java.text.DecimalFormat; //Configures output for dollar amounts
 import java.util.InputMismatchException; //Checks for invalid user input

 public class AnnualSalary
 {      
 public void displayMessage()
 {
    //display intro message to calculator
    System.out.println("Annual Compensation Calculator");
 }        
 public static void main (String[] args,)
 {

    double salary; //This is the annual sales value
    double rate; //Commission rate once minimum sales reached
    double commission; //This is the amount of commision made
    double pay; //Salesperson's total pay
    double sales; //annual sales, prompted user input
    double incentive; //bonus rate once sales target is exceeded
    double max; //sets maximum sales amount to calculate for potential earnings table
    boolean isValidNumber=false; //default flag for numeric sales input
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ); //allows user input from command window

    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    salary = 50000.00;
    rate = 0.05;
    incentive = 0.0625;
    sales = 0;
    max = sales * 1.5;

    System.out.println(" Enter The Annual Sales "); //prompt for input from user

    while(!isValidNumber) //Continue to prompt user until a valid number is entered
    {    
        try //try/catch block to handle invalid characters.
        {  
            sales = input.nextDouble(); //Read number from user, if alpha character is               keyed then an exception is thrown
            isValidNumber = true; //Set our flag so we can exit the loop      
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ioe) //Catch input not matching excpected type.
        {                  
            System.out.println("Please enter a numeric value."); //re-prompt user
            input.next(); //If Scanner translates successfully it advances, however if it fails it must be manually advanced.
        }
    }    

    while (sales < 96000.00) //conditional statement for sales below 80% of goal
    {
        pay = salary ;
        System.out.println("Total Annual Compensation is $"+dollar.format(pay));
    }
    while (sales >= 96000.00 && sales <= 120000.00) //conditional statement for sales 80%-100% of goal
    {
        commission = sales * rate;
        pay = commission + salary;
        System.out.println("Total Annual Compensation is $"+dollar.format(pay));
    }
    while (sales > 120000.00) //conditional statement for sales exceeding goal
    {    
        commission = sales * incentive;
        pay = commission + salary;
        System.out.println("For: $" + sales + "   The Total Compensation is: $" +dollar.format(pay));
    }            

    while(sales < max) //This sets the while loop to start at minimum & end at the max
    { 
        sales = sales + 5000;
        if (sales < 96000.00) //conditional statement for sales below 80% of goal
        {
        pay = salary;
        }
        else if (sales >= 96000.00 && sales <= 120000.00)
        {
        commission = sales * rate;
        pay = commission + salary;
        }
        while (sales > 120000.00) //conditional statement for sales exceeding goal
        {    
        commission = sales * incentive;
        pay = commission + salary;
        System.out.println("For: $" + sales + "   The Total Compensation is: $" +dollar.format(pay));
        }  
        } //Ends the body of the while loop.
    }
}    //end calculator'
```

Comment: `public static void main (String[] args,)` **illegal**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `,`. It must be the cause of that error.

```
public static void main (String[] args) // No comma
```

As for your second question, you must ask yourself, what are the unitary operations you want to make.

Each of you while loop make a special treatment. Maybe you want to separate those treatment in specific methods ?

I see there's one used to get data from the user. You could make a method whose goal is to ask for these data then return them to the main program, etc.

Also, you might want to create a specific class for the calculator itself and in another, use it to make your treatment.

Since you said that you were beginning. I think this would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args,)
```

Should be

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public static void main (String[] args,)

                              --------^  //extra comma here
```

to

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma after your argument for main.

```
public static void main(String[] args,)
```

Try removing the comma.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

To split your program in several classes, you should read about Refactoring and Design Patterns. The great "Gang of Four" wrote excellent books to learn.
Design Patterns are a way to give a nice structure to a program, making it handy for the programmer.
Refactoring is changing the structure of your code to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `,` from the `public static void main (String[] args,)`. This will solve your current problem.

On a side note, for the problem you're likely to face in the future(and probably leading to the creation of another SO question),

Change the `while` to `if` in the below mentioned statements.

```
while (sales < 96000.00)

while (sales >= 96000.00 && sales <= 120000.00)

while (sales > 120000.00)

while (sales < max)

while (sales > 120000.00)
```